# How to check if all required columns or any one from required column is available or not python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I folder with multiple text files , i am reading files from folder in loop and do process with 10 columns , i want to check if A , C  and D columns available in dataframe then do further process otherwise just go for next file

simply if we want to check availability of one column i know we can use this.

```
if 'A' in df:
   print('yes')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `issubset()` method returns `True` if all elements of a set are present in another set (passed as an argument). If not, it returns `False`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],

})

print (set(['A', 'C', 'D']).issubset(df.columns))
True
print (set(['A',  'E']).issubset(df.columns))
False
```

So use:

```
if (set(['A', 'C', 'D']).issubset(df.columns)):
    print ('yes')
    yes
```

EDIT:

The `isdisjoint()` method returns `True` if two sets are disjoint sets. If not, it returns `False`.

```
print (not set(['A', 'C', 'D']).isdisjoint(df.columns))
True
print (not set(['A', 'E']).isdisjoint(df.columns))
True

print (not set(['R', 'E']).isdisjoint(df.columns))
False
```

---

The `intersection()` method returns a new set with elements that are common to all sets. Then if convert to bool, empty set return `False`:

```
print (bool(set(['A', 'C', 'D']).intersection(df.columns)))
True
print (bool(set(['A', 'E']).intersection(df.columns)))
True
print (bool(set(['R', 'E']).intersection(df.columns)))
False
```

Comment: according to this it will process the file if columns A,C,D will available in df but i want if all three or any of one from these available in df then process the file